# docker - can't connect to external postgres db

Tags: postgresql, docker

We're running a docker container that connects to a postgres database on the same server but not within a container.

I can connect via psql or pgadmin fine but within the docklet we are seeing the following errors messages coming from Catalina.

Apologies on the unformatted mess but the crux is that the following error is coming up:

```
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Here's the relevant dump from the logs:

```
  <table border="0" class="BodyTable">
     <tr><td><div class="GroupHdr">Detailed Error Report</div><table class='TopError' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' width='100%' border='0'><tr><td><b>There was an error while processing your request.</b></td></tr><tr><td><b>Message: </b><br/>Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.</td></tr><tr><td><b>Source: </b><br/></td></tr><tr><td><b>Stack Trace: </b><br/> at system.Data.ProviderBase.AbstractDBConnection.OnSqlException(AbstractDBConnection.cs:434)<br/>   at system.Data.ProviderBase.AbstractDBConnection.Open(AbstractDBConnection.cs:505)<br/> at rdServer.rdSqlReader.<init>(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.access$4500(Unknown Source)<br/>   at rdServer.rdDb.a(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.b(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.a(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.xmlGetData(Unknown Source)<br/>    at rdServer.rdDb.xmlGetDataDocument(Unknown Source)<br/>    at rdServer.rdDb9.xmlGetDataDocument(Unknown Source)<br/>   at rdServer.PageBuilder.V(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.o(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.S(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.Q(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.R(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.o(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.S(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.Q(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.R(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.m(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.g(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.BuildHtml(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.ResponseBuilder.BuildResponse(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.ResponseBuilder.BuildResponse(Unknown Source)<br/>  at ASP.rdpage_aspx.__Render__control1(rdPage.aspx:4)<br/>   at ASP.rdpage_aspx$__Impl0.Invoke(Unknown Source)<br/>  at system.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(Control.cs:1101)<br/>   at system.Web.UI.Control.Render(Control.cs:1090)<br/>   at system.Web.UI.Page.Render(Page.cs:1095)<br/> at system.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(Control.cs:1254)<br/>    at system.Web.UI.Page.RenderPage(Page.cs:1621)<br/> at system.Web.UI.Page.encodeChildren(Page.jvm.cs:159)<br/>  at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseFacesViewHandler.renderView(BaseFacesViewHandler.cs:58)<br/>    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)<br/> at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)<br/>   at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.ServletFacesPageHandler.ProcessRequest(ServletFacesPageHandler.cs:116)<br/> at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.SessionWrapper$SessionWrapperHandler.ProcessRequest(SessionWrapper.cs:40)<br/>  at system.Web.HttpApplication$Pipelined__7.MoveNext$Z$$_$Pipeline$_$d__7$$(HttpApplication.cs:1033)<br/>    at system.Web.HttpApplication.Tick(HttpApplication.cs:705)<br/> at system.Web.HttpApplication.Start(HttpApplication.cs:1217)<br/>   at system.Web.HttpApplication.System_Web_IHttpAsyncHandler_BeginProcessRequest(HttpApplication.cs:1319)<br/>    at system.Web.HttpRuntime.RealProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:482)<br/>   at system.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:523)<br/>   at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseHttpServlet.service(BaseHttpServlet.cs:200)<br/>    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)<br/>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)<br/>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)<br/>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)<br/> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)<br/> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)<br/>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)<br/>    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)<br/> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)<br/>    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)<br/> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)<br/> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)<br/> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)<br/> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)<br/>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)<br/> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)<br/> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)<br/>  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/><br/></td></tr></table><table class='InnerError' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' width='100%' border='0'><tr class='InnerErrorMessage'><td><b>Inner error:</b></td></tr><tr><td><b>Message: </b><br/>Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.</td></tr><tr><td><b>Source: </b><br/></td></tr><tr><td><b>Stack Trace: </b><br/>    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:361)<br/>  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:284)<br/>  at Mainsoft.Data.Jdbc.Providers.GenericProvider$JdbcUrlConnector.get_Connection(GenericProvider.cs:183)<br/>    at Mainsoft.Data.Jdbc.Providers.GenericProvider.GetConnection(GenericProvider.cs:336)<br/>  at system.Data.ProviderBase.AbstractDBConnection.Open(AbstractDBConnection.cs:495)<br/> at rdServer.rdSqlReader.<init>(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.access$4500(Unknown Source)<br/>   at rdServer.rdDb.a(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.b(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.a(Unknown Source)<br/> at rdServer.rdDb.xmlGetData(Unknown Source)<br/>    at rdServer.rdDb.xmlGetDataDocument(Unknown Source)<br/>    at rdServer.rdDb9.xmlGetDataDocument(Unknown Source)<br/>   at rdServer.PageBuilder.V(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.o(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.S(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.Q(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.R(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.o(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.S(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.Q(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.R(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.m(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.g(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.PageBuilder.BuildHtml(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.ResponseBuilder.BuildResponse(Unknown Source)<br/>  at rdServer.ResponseBuilder.BuildResponse(Unknown Source)<br/>  at ASP.rdpage_aspx.__Render__control1(rdPage.aspx:4)<br/>   at ASP.rdpage_aspx$__Impl0.Invoke(Unknown Source)<br/>  at system.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(Control.cs:1101)<br/>   at system.Web.UI.Control.Render(Control.cs:1090)<br/>   at system.Web.UI.Page.Render(Page.cs:1095)<br/> at system.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(Control.cs:1254)<br/>    at system.Web.UI.Page.RenderPage(Page.cs:1621)<br/> at system.Web.UI.Page.encodeChildren(Page.jvm.cs:159)<br/>  at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseFacesViewHandler.renderView(BaseFacesViewHandler.cs:58)<br/>    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)<br/> at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)<br/>   at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.ServletFacesPageHandler.ProcessRequest(ServletFacesPageHandler.cs:116)<br/> at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.SessionWrapper$SessionWrapperHandler.ProcessRequest(SessionWrapper.cs:40)<br/>  at system.Web.HttpApplication$Pipelined__7.MoveNext$Z$$_$Pipeline$_$d__7$$(HttpApplication.cs:1033)<br/>    at system.Web.HttpApplication.Tick(HttpApplication.cs:705)<br/> at system.Web.HttpApplication.Start(HttpApplication.cs:1217)<br/>   at system.Web.HttpApplication.System_Web_IHttpAsyncHandler_BeginProcessRequest(HttpApplication.cs:1319)<br/>    at system.Web.HttpRuntime.RealProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:482)<br/>   at system.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:523)<br/>   at Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseHttpServlet.service(BaseHttpServlet.cs:200)<br/>    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)<br/>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)<br/>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)<br/>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)<br/> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)<br/> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)<br/>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)<br/>    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)<br/> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)<br/>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)<br/>    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)<br/> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)<br/> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)<br/> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)<br/> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)<br/>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)<br/> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)<br/> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)<br/>  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/><br/></td></tr></table><table class='InnerError' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' width='100%' border='0'><tr class='InnerErrorMessage'><td><b>Inner error:</b></td></tr><tr><td><b>Message: </b><br/>Connection refused</td></tr><tr><td><b>Source: </b><br/></td></tr><tr><td><b>Stack Trace: </b><br/>   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)<br/>   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)<br/>    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)<br/> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)<br/>  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)<br/>  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)<br/>    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)<br/>    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60)<br/>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:101)<br/> at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)<br/> at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:138)<br/>   at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)<br/>    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)<br/> at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)<br/>    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)<br/>    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)<br/>   at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:46)<br/>    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:321)<br/>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/><br/></td></tr></table></td></tr>
  </table>
```

The docker container runs it's own separate network which can connect to the external network (we know as it successfully makes an api call to another IP).  Our suspicion is something in postgres is causing a block however no other applications on this server have any issues accessing postgres.

Comment: What is it that "docklet" that you mention? How do you determine the IP address to connect to? How is the Docker network configured?

Comment: updated correcting verbage and adding more information.  unfortunately I didn't make the docker container I'm merely digging in the logs.  Everyone is stumped so I'm literally throwing things against the wall here.

Comment: so, do you think it is a docker or a postgresql problem? Is the other IP that you can reach from the docker container in the same network like the DB? Can you post the logs of the container? `docker logs CONTAINER`

Comment: Other applications may make _local_ connections to Postgres on the same server, while the connection from a Docker container will appear as _remote_ to the database. What is the Postgres' `listen_address` parameter set to? Do you allow remote connections from the Docker IP in the HBA file?

Comment: the problem was another external app which it connects to... I had to change `DB_HOST=localhost` to `DB_HOST=192.168.1.1` and fine!

Comment: @whoisearth then answer your own question please :)